# Quality / price slider

Tags: usability, mobile, sliders, ratings

I am trying to depict quality (custom rating) and price sliders in one phone screen. The problem is that price and quality does not have direct connection (i.e. high quality does not necessary mean high price…there may be high quality and medium or low price). Is there any suggestion to do it? Maybe anybody know how to combine them into one slider?

Comment: Why do you want to combine them given that they don't have a direct connection?

Comment: What are their purpose? Does the user slide them in to place, then click "search" or something, or do they appear from the system to show an item's stats? Need more information

Comment: @Kirill It would be better, if you can elaborate more to this. What's the purpose and a bit Graphical explanation would be great!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to combine them into one control - which does seem far-fetched - the result is going to depend a lot more on the algorithm you use to display the "results" than the control itself.

I would agree with other commenters that it does not seem like such a good idea to try and combine these metrics (without knowing a lot more about your requirements and audience). It seems as if setting the desired quality with a slider and then showing all price options that result for that quality level.

But more details about your situation may result in better answers :-)